# List comprehension in python not evaluating correctly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and am trying to teach myself. I have a tic-tac-toe game I have been working on for a while now but I cannot make it detect ties. I am using a list to store the values and list comprehension to detect ties/wins. The problem is that the program is not evaluating correctly. It returns False when it should return True.

This is my function that detects the tie:

```
def tied():
        nonlocal tie
        if all([x in ['X', 'O'] for x in o_gb[0]] + [x in ['X', 'O']
              for x in o_gb[1]] + [x in ['X', 'O'] for x in o_gb[2]]):
        tie = True
```

It always return a list of False even if There are X's or O's in the list.

Here is all of my code:

```
    import numpy as np

    def ticTacToe():
        x_win = False
        o_win = False
        tie = False
        o_gb = [['_'for x in range(3)]for y in range(3)]
               gb = np.array(o_gb).T

        def win():
            nonlocal x_win, o_win
            if (all(x in ['X'] for x in gb[0]) or all(x in ['X']for x in 
               gb[1])or all(x in ['X'] for x in gb[2])):
                x_win = True
            if (all(x in ['O'] for x in gb[0]) or all(x in ['O'] for x in 
               gb[1])or all(x in ['O'] for x in gb[2])):
                o_win = True

        def win2():
            nonlocal x_win, o_win
            if (all(x in ['X'] for x in gb[:, 0]) or all(x in ['X']for x in 
               gb[:, 1]) or all(x in ['X'] for x in gb[:, 2])):
                x_win = True
            if (all(x in ['O'] for x in gb[:, 0]) or all(x in ['O']for x in 
               gb[:, 1]) or all(x in ['O'] for x in gb[:, 2])):
                o_win = True

        def win3():
            nonlocal x_win, o_win
            if (all(x in ['X'] for x in np.diag(gb)) or all(x in ['X'] for x 
               in np.diag(np.fliplr(gb)))):
                x_win = True
            if (all(x in ['O'] for x in np.diag(gb)) or all(x in ['O'] for x 
               in np.diag(np.fliplr(gb)))):
                o_win = True

        def tied():
            nonlocal tie
            if all([x in ['X', 'O'] for x in o_gb[0]] + [x in ['X', 'O']for 
               x in o_gb[1]] + [x in ['X', 'O'] for x in o_gb[2]]):
                tie = True
        while 1:
            print(gb)
            xm = input('X\'s move(x,y): ').split(',')
            xm = [int(i) for i in xm]
            if gb[xm[0]-1, xm[1]-1] not in ['X', 'O']:
                gb[xm[0]-1, xm[1]-1] = 'X'
            else:
                 print('You can\'t move there, now you lose a turn!')
            win()
            win2()
            win3()
            tied()
            print(gb)
            if o_win or x_win or tie:
                break
            om = input('O\'s move(x,y): ').split(',')
            om = [int(i) for i in om]
            if gb[om[0]-1, om[1]-1] not in ['X', 'O']:
                gb[om[0]-1, om[1]-1] = 'O'
            else:
                print('You can\'t move there, now you lose a turn!')
            win()
            win2()
            win3()
            tied()
            if o_win or x_win or tie:
                break
            if x_win:
                print('X wins!')
            elif o_win:
                print(gb)
                print('O wins!')
            else:
                if o_win:
                    print(gb)
                print('Tie!')
            while 1:
                done = input('Again?(y/n)')
                if done in ['y']:
                    ticTacToe()
            else:
                break
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` checks for all, you need `any` (and simplify your code):

```
def tied():
    nonlocal tie
    if any(x in 'XO' for i in o_gb[:3] for x in i):
        tie = True
```

then simplify it like this in all functions